# Identifying columns or rows that have a color in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question though. Is it possible to identify if the columns/rows contains a color using VBA? For example, I have columns A to Z with 5000 rows. In row 630, there are columns that highlighted in red, and I want to marked it as "RED" in Column AA. Another example, in row 2533, Column G it is highlighted in Red, and should indicate "RED" as well in Column AA. Rows that doesn't contain any color should be marked as WHITE. Is it possible in VBA to do that scenario?

Comment: You need to identify whether *any* cell in a row has a color?

Comment: yes, I need to identify whether any cell in a has a color and need to marked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

Notice, it will check row wise!! So if you have colour in column G, but not in Column A. It will give you the word "colour" in Column AA. I also choose to check background colour.. not red particular because sometimes people choose different "red".

If you only want red (RGB 255,0,0) use the second IF statement and comment out the first one.

```
Sub CheckColurRows()

Dim myRange As Range
Dim cl As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set myRange = ws.Range("A1:Z5000") 'Set range


For Each cl In myRange 'Loop through each cell in "myRange
    If cl.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlColorIndexNone Then 'Check if cell has any background colour (not only red)
    'If cl.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then 'Check if cell only has red colour
        ws.Cells(cl.Row, 27) = "Colour" 'If cell has colour, then print the word "Colour" in Column 27 (Column AA)
    Else
        If ws.Cells(cl.Row, 27) <> "Colour" Then ws.Cells(cl.Row, 27) = "White" 'If cell already have the word colour in column AA, don't overwrite with "white"
    End If
Next cl

End Sub
```

Result will be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub FFF()
    Dim rngRow As Range, cell As Range, red_color&
    red_color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    For Each rngRow In Range("A1:Z5000").Rows
        For Each cell In rngRow.Cells
            cell = IIf(cell.Interior.Color = red_color, "RED", "WHITE")
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```